# firefox proxy switching

Tags: proxy, firefox

We have the P.C. users running unprivileged which means they can't change their proxy settings in IE, however with firefox installed they can, I prefer them to use firefox, is there any way to stop firefox allowing proxy settings to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using this information:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that. I have since thought that using a transparent proxy might be the cleanest solution, to cover all browser possibilities.  But I didn't ask that question.